# python exception within if and try block

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm writing a python client to a web-service (REST) using requests

I want to raise except with the user enters bad credentials

I have the following code block

```
    try:
        ret=self.req_session.get(URL)
        if (ret.status_code == 401):
            raise Authexecption("Improper credentials")
        else:
            ret.raise_for_status()               
    except Authexecption:
        logging.error("Unable to authenticate. Please check you credentails")
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        logging.error("Issue with communicating with Web-Services. The HTTP response is " + str(ret.status_code))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        logging.error("Time out while connecting to the Web-Service..")
```

The Idea here being, that I will raise a custom error message for auth issues, and a generic one for all other issues (5xx,404 etc..)

when I execute this I get the following error

```
    except Authexecption:
NameError: global name 'Authexecption' is not defined
```

I'm pretty new to python and trying to learn, how do i fix this?

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, have you defined `Authexecption`? Did you maybe mean `Authexception` (spelled correctly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define custom exceptions first:

```
class AuthException(Exception):  # Authexecption may be misspelled...
    pass
```

maybe there is a better exception to inherit from than the base exception `Exception`. have a look at the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

Comment: Yes I did add it, still I got the same error message. The mistake I did was to add the Authexecption class with the class that I was calling this code.   I moved this class as a top level class definition, and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says that python cannot find the class `Authexception`. That is, it does not exist or it was not imported.

To fix this, you need to create it first:

```
class AuthException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errors):
        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        super(AuthException, self).__init__(message)
```

and then import it wherever you need.